# What is the max amps for the Adam 6050 module

Tags: amperage, io

I recently purchased an Adam 6050 module and need to power it up.  However [the manual](http://downloadt.advantech.com/ProductFile/Downloadfile1/1-V0SCSR/UM-ADAM-6000-Ed6-0-6-EN.pdf) seems a little vague, other than mentioning that it has a 10-30 volt unregulated power range.  And that it consumes 2W at 24V.

Near the bottom of the manual I found a note saying to use the [power module PWR-244](http://downloadt.advantech.com/ProductFile/Downloadfile2/1-35JFBK/PWR-244_DS.pdf) as an FCC approved power source.  That power module is listed as having an output of 24V and 4.2 A max.

I have a little AC/DC power adapter that I can plug into the wall that outputs 24V and 800 mA.  I don't think I will blow up the adam module with that, am I correct?  The worst case scenario I can come up with is that it won't work because the adam module might need more ampers to function.

Comment: If it consumes 2W at 24V, how much current is that, and can your 800mA adapter supply at least that much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I got an answer from the ADAM technical support staff:

Hello,

Referring to the General (power input) section of the datasheet.

Any power supply that provides 24VDC will be fine as long as it delivers at least 2 watts (about 1/10 of a amp).  More watts/amps are fine, the ADAM only uses what it needs.

(the DO channels are not sourcing, so you aren’t going to get an output of any voltage.  As they are sinking outputs, the voltage/amps run to the remote device and the negative leg connects back to the ADAM DO channel.  This you do have to be careful of, more than 100mA through the DO channel will damage it)

Answer (score 0):

In reply to the comment above.  ( Watts = Amps * Volts ) so 24V * .8A = 19.2 Watts, which is more than enough for the 2W required.

This is a formula that is ingrained in all you electrical engineers.  I had to look it back up from my college physics days.  I have been using it a lot more lately in my electrical hobbyist pursuits.

I think the most important part of the answer I received is that the device is capable of handling more than the 2W required.  Not all devices are, I have blown up some devices by plugging them into a power brick providing the correct voltage but far too many amps.  I am sure the answer I received is not 100% accurate, there is likely a limit to the amps the adam module can handle, but i'm guessing the engineers believe it to be high enough not to mention.